# About the words "anything but"

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity, phrase-usage

I am unsure about the possible meaning(s) of this phrase. Does a sentence like

*"She did anything but sleep"*

mean something like she is a very dilligent or very lazy person depending on context?

How about these sentences, do they make sense?

- *"She is responsible for the project being completed on schedule. She did anything but sleep these last few days."*
- *"This is the best movie I've seen for a long time. It is anything but wonderful."*

Comment: It depends on if you think sleeping implies laziness or not. In the full context of the example sentence, it strongly suggests that she was *not* lazy.

Comment: In your first sentence, “but” means except. So she was not sleeping. “Anything but sleep” is the opposite of “nothing but sleep.”

Comment: 'I' must see some very poor films to make the second example even near-acceptable. 'X did anything but V' is usually used to mean X was supposed to [do] V but instead indulged in all sorts of  distractions.

Comment: could the second sentence be improved by saying "it is nothing but wonderful?"